# How to place text over font awesome icon?

Tags: css

I would like to create a `div` with text `Some meaningful text` and a heart icon behind word `meaningful` exactly.

I am using [font awesome icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/heart?style=solid), so the icon is `<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>` with width.

How can I can achieve with existing DOM?

```
<div id="text-over-icon">
  <span>Some</span>
  <span>meaningful</span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Hopefully, it can be done without `float` or `position: absolute`.

Comment: Using `position: absolute` is the best options for this reqirement

Comment: Why not `position: absolute` ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak `position: absolute` will depend on the nearest non-static element like an anchor, when in future I accidentally change the intermediate element I am not aware, I may break the behavior. I hope to find a hierarchically independent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hopefully, it can be done without float or position: absolute.*

You can make use of CSS grid, and position both items on the same column/row.

The only drawback is you'll have to edit the html and nest another span to wrap the text.

```css
[grid] {
  display: inline-grid;
}

[grid]>i {
  grid-row: 1/1;
  grid-column: 1/1;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

[grid]>span {
  grid-row: 1/1;
  grid-column: 1/1
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<div id="text-over-icon">
  <span>Some</span>
  <span grid>
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
    <span>meaningful</span>
  </span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! Exactly what I want!

Comment: @Mike FYI this is not a hierarchically independent solution, you'll need `display:grid` on the wrapper which is the same if we use position absolute we need at least `position:relative` on the wrapper. https://jsfiddle.net/dLyftowz/

Comment: For simple case they may be identical, but `display: grid` is one-level while `position: absolute` may be positioned to a weird place with parent modified, which could lead to debugging difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:absolute` you can achieve this

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.fa.fa-heart {
  color: #ff0;
}

.fa.fa-heart:before {
  font-size: 50px;
}

#text-over-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="parent">
  <div class="fa fa-heart"></div>
  <div id="text-over-icon">
    <span>Some</span>
    <span>meaningful</span>
    <span>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```